# what is link baiting? What is the process?

Tags: backlinks

I am not familiar with the term `Link baiting`what is it and how can I use it in seo.

Is it useful?

can anyone describe it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Matt Cutts defines link bait as anything "interesting enough to catch people's attention."

Further answer of your question. http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-linkbait-and-linkbaiting/